# Changing default cache storage name of service worker (workbox)

Tags: javascript, workbox

I have an SPA with two main entrypoints: `index.html` and `proxy.html`. I also have a service worker (built with Workbox) that precaches these two entrypoints.

My code looks like this:

```js
import { registerRoute, NavigationRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from "workbox-precaching";

precacheAndRoute([
  {
    url: "/index.html",
    revision: ...autogenerated...,
  },
  {
    url: "/proxy.html",
    revision: ...autogenerated...,
  },
]);

const handler = createHandlerBoundToURL("/index.html");
const navigationRoute = new NavigationRoute(handler, {
  denylist: [new RegExp("/proxy.html")]
});
registerRoute(navigationRoute);
```

This code works as expected (both files are precached and then my SPA can work offline), but I saw that the cache storage in which these two files are stored is called `workbox-precache-v2-<my domain>`.

Is there a way I can change that name to something more specific, like `html-assets`?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use this:

```
setCacheNameDetails({
  prefix: "",
  precache: "html-assets",
  suffix: "",
});

// Precache HTMLs for offline usage
precacheAndRoute([
  {
    url: "/index.html",
    revision: process.env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP,
  },
  {
    url: "/proxy.html",
    revision: process.env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP,
  },
]);
```